# How to extract every text element from a class using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from time import sleep
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def get_coin():
    response = requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content , 'html.parser')
    name = soup.find_all('p',class_='sc-1eb5slv-0 iJjGCS')
    for s in name:
        print(s.text)
get_coin()
```

This code returns the following output

```
Bitcoin
Ethereum
Binance Coin
Dogecoin
XRP
Tether
Cardano
Polkadot
Bitcoin Cash
Litecoin
```

But the problem is the website contains 100 such elements but the code prints only 10 of them.
Please advise on how to extract all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_coin():
    response = requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    table = soup.find_all("tbody")[0]
    rows = table.find_all("tr")
    names = [row.find_all("span")[3].getText() for row in rows]
    # Return clean and sorted results
    return sorted([name for name in names if not name[0].isdigit()])

print(get_coin())
# Outputs
['Aave', 'Algorand', 'Ankr', ..., 'Zcash', 'Zilliqa', 'yearn.finance']
```